# Http xmpp multithread process

Tags: python, multithreading, http, xmpp, job-queue

I am using a python library called sleekxmpp to imeplement xmpp protocol.
Actually, the whole process is, a client send a http request to me, then I need to send xmpp messages to other clients through my sleekxmpp library.
I need to gather those http request in queue and my sleekxmpp need to longlive listening to the queue and send xmpp message out.
Is there any library in python can help me do that?

Comment: Perhaps http://www.zeromq.org/ can help you.